# Powershell: Get the default directory from inside a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm writing a powershell cmdlet.  From inside of my cmdlet BeginProcessing() method, I want to be able to retrieve the the directory that was the default directory at the time the cmdlet was invoked.

Example:
If the user does this:

```
cd \myDirectory
invoke-mycmdlet
```

I want for my code to know that the default shell directory was c:\myDirectory.
When I access Environment.CurrentDirectory, it's always c:\windows\system32

I've seen a similar post on SO where the poster needed to set Environment::Current directory from inside the shell using get-location.  That won't work for me.

Basically, my cmdlet does some file system stuff, and I want the user to be able to just cd\ into a directory, and execute my cmdlet, with it operating on the directory that they switched into -- just like you would expect it to work from the old Command Console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try this instead, CurrentLocation.Path could also point to other provider paths, such as the registery.

```
this.SessionState.Path.CurrentFileSystemLocation.Path
```

Comment: I like your answer more than mine -- FTW!

Answer (score 1):

You know, I always seem to find it right after I post -- regardless of how long I spent looking before reaching for SO!

So, my cmdlet inherits from PsCmdlet.  I found that I could get the path I wanted from

```
this.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.Path
```

(where "this" is a cmdlet class that inherits from PsCmdlet)

Answer (score -1):

Try the `Get-Location` cmdlet. It should be the script's current executing location, rather than the powershell host startup folder.

Comment: Or you can just check $PWD.